# Disconnecting and Reconnecting Users on Mosquitto: Test Commands Needed

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm looking for the command to forcibly disconnect a user and then allow them to reconnect on Mosquitto. This is for testing purposes. Can anyone provide the necessary commands for achieving this?

And I'm wondering if there is a specific command to view the IP addresses of users currently connected to the broker.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, there is no way to do this apart from connecting as another client using the same client id.

The MQTT spec says that the broker **MUST** disconnect any existing client if a second connects with the same client id, so you could connect a second client then disconnect and allow the first to reconnect.

For the second question (SO questions should only really have 1 topic). There is nothing in mosquitto that will tell you this, the best you can do is parse the log messages for clients connecting and disconnecting.

If you have sufficient permissions and mosquitto is running on a linux machine then you could use a tool like `lsof` to see what external IP addresses are connected to the ports mosquitto is listening on.